# What not to commit FlutterFire?

Tags: flutter, firebase, gitignore

I have a Flutter project which has Firebase connected For Flutter(Android, iOS, Web).
I have a doubt that what are the files and folder which is not recommended to commit on git and **must** be included in `.gitignore`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while you configure the flutter project with flutterfire cli, it generates a  firebase_options.dart, but you can share the project everywhere but for every use on a different machines you should have the flutterfire cli on that machines and configure it again.

so you don't really need to care about this !

Comment: Are you sure about it?
because I am going to push it in my public Git.

Comment: since the flutterfire team commit the firebase config files in their repositories, I say that there is no problem to commit them, check [link](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/example/lib/firebase_config.dart)